# Cannot make backup or do a factory reset on Samsung Galaxy A40

Tags: samsung, backup, factory-reset

I need to make a backup on Samsung Galaxy A40 to factory reset my phone because I'm having a problem with it. I cannot log in. Every time I log in, it gets stuck at "Starting Android". If I turn my phone on/off normally, it gets an absurd timeout. Removing my SIM card doesn't change anything. For that, I cannot fully restart it because you need to log in for that, and I need my stuff before I reset it. I also cannot use the volume down button because it's broken and the ADB is not authorized.

EDIT:

There is no way to do it in my case there are a few tricks that can help someone else though:

- If you cannot restart your phone because you are logged out do the following; remove SIM card tray and put it back in, when you can put the PIN in for the SIM card hold the power button.
- If you cannot come in the recovery menu with your volume down do; restart your A40 (tap the restart button twice) then keep holding [power+volume up] until the recovery menu shows up.
- Are you stuck at "Starting Android" and cant do anything; swipe down from the top, where your notifacations and flash light are in the upper right corner is a settings cog, press that an you get to the settings menu note that not everything works in there!